# UML: how component can implement some interface?

Tags: java, uml

Could anyone explain how component in uml can provide some interface. I can't understand it because component is not a class which can implement interfaces. If it possible please provide a short example in Java.

Comment: See [uml-diagrams.org: UML Component Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams-examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a component in Java. One can consider a JAR file to be a component that provides one or more interfaces. One can segregate an entire system into chunks this way. Each chunk can be separately deployed and versioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you say where is the port (of component) in your example?

Comment: A port is nothing concrete. It's a means of bundling interfaces. Think of it as parts of a socket where one supplies power and the other supplies data connectors (interfaces).

Comment: A port in UML is a distinct interaction point between a containing class and any number of contained classes. A port is a property of the containing class, typically typed by one or more interfaces. Something (like a class) implements that interface and may delegate each operation to a contained class. In my simple example, there might be no port. One would have to designate a containing class in the JAR file having a property typed by an interface. Ostensibly, a caller would have to ask the containing class for a reference to the port.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: Why do you claim a port is nothing concrete?

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I can point at something that realizes a package, port, interface, or class. Do you mean that they are not concrete because one cannot always reverse the process and infer architecture from code?

Comment: I just would not put much more meaning into a port than packaging interfaces. That's all. You answer is perfect. I'm just trying to add explanation for the port thingy.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I don't agree with it. Jar file is not a component. It is artifact. Maybe your answer is good for uml 1, but not for uml 2 I consider.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is about component diagram. Then Component diagram does not represent your classes, interfaces and functions. It is represented in class diagram.

Component diagram represents functional components in your application and its dependencies.

Hope this helps!